# Инициализация итератора

Tags: c++, vector

```
vector<int> m={1,2,3};
m.begin()++;
cout<<m[0];}
```

Вопрос, почему не изменяется значение итератора на 0-й элемент?

Comment: Потому что ты звёздочку не поставил.

Comment: @Qwertiy звёздочку ГДЕ?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, тут: `*m.begin()++;`. Там Harry давно подробно расписал.

Comment: @Qwertiy разыменованием ты получишь значение элемента через итератор. Но `begin` на другое место указывать никак не станет, как и `m[0]`.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, я в курсе, но подозреваю, что спрашивающий именно это и хотел сделать?

Comment: Наблюдаемое поведение тут только через `cout` происходит. По твоему предложению в комменте ничего не изменится в этой части.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что делает `m.begin()` - возвращает итератор (т.е. экземпляр типа `iterator` для специфического типа вектора). Этот итератор представляет собой новый безымянный объект, значение которого указывает на начало вектора `m`.

Далее `++` выполняет постинкремент этого безымянного объекта. После `;` этот объект перестаёт существовать.

```
m.begin()++;
           ^--- безымянный объект, для которого был выполнен инкремент, умирает
```

Дальнейший вывод `m[0]` представляет собой вызов `operator[]` для вектора, который перегружен для предоставления доступа к элементам по индексу. В данном случае там (по индексу `0`) расположена `1`, которой проинициализирован в первой строке начальный элемент массива. Этот вывод вообще никак не связан с выполненным ранее инкрементом безымянного объекта итератора, который был получен строкой выше.

---

Если хочется вывести значение через итератор, и при этом, чтобы был выведен следующий элемент массива, можно написать так:

```
auto it = m.begin() + 1;
cout << *it;              // выведет 2 (т.е. элемент m[1])
```

Или однострочник:

```
cout << *(m.begin() + 1);
```

---

Если нужно изменить непосредственно сам элемент `m[0]`, то надо выполнить инкремент **после** разыменования итератора:

```
(*m.begin())++;
cout << m[0];              // выведет 2 (т.е. увеличенный элемент m[0])
```

Для однострочного варианта, чтобы значение сразу стало наблюдаемым, постинкремент следует заменить преинкрементом:

```
cout << ++*m.begin();
```

Comment: а можно ли как-то изменить положение итератора, не на 0 объект, чтобы begin() вернул мне не безымянный объект, а именно себя?

Comment: @Sashkinzz так `it` как раз указывает на `m[1]`. Если вопрос про `begin()`, то результат вызова этой функции всегда указывает на начало, она для этого задумана. Вернуть "себя" можно, если возвращать ссылку на какое-то внутреннее представление. Но мы же про `std::vector` рассуждаем, для него поведение стандартизировано.

Comment: Однострочник с `++` - не очень. Нет гарантии, что это вообще скомпилируется для rvalue (например если итератор - сырой указатель).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat теоретически, да. А на практике для `std::vector`?

Comment: Хмм, проверил, все три крупные стандартные библиотеки пропускают. Но я бы все равно писал с `std::next()` или `+ 1`.

Answer (score 2):

Рассмотрим код

```
int a = 5;
int * p = &a;
```

Ds ощущаете разницу между

```
(*p)++;
```

и

```
p++;
```

? В первом случае это инкремент того, на что указатель указывает, во втором — просто инкремент указателя.

Вот примерно то же самое и с итераторами: итератор по сути аналог указателя.